# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.StatelessSession.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query;

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

I've been upgrading my frameworks (spring-ws, spring, spring-batch, hibernate) to the latest versions.

```
 compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-core', version: '3.0.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '5.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '5.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-core', version: '4.0.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-infrastructure', version: '4.0.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.6.Final'
```

Everything seem to work fine except when i execute spring batch job, i get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.StatelessSession.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query;
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.getForwardOnlyCursor(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:122)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doOpen(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:185)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.open(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I see that HibernateItemReaderHelper calls the createQuery method, inside this method the createQuery method of StatelessSession is called.

HibernateItemReaderHelper.creatQuery returns an object of org.hibernate.query.Query;
StatelessSession.createQuery returns an object of org.hibernate.Query

I' think that is the problem, but how can i fix this?
Please help

Comment: I second the answer by @dimitrisli . See my comment there.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring Batch Core 4.0.1.RELEASE** seems to be compatible with **Hibernate 5.2.12.Final** [as can be seen in its tag build.gradle dependency file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.0.1.RELEASE/build.gradle#L73) so give that a try instead of your explicit version **5.3.6.Final**.

Comment: I second this answer. Either downgrade your hibernate version to `5.2.12.Final` (or the latest 5.2.x which is `5.2.17.Final` as of writing this) or upgrade Spring Batch to 4.1.0.RC1 where hibernate version has been upgraded to `5.3.6.Final`.